# How do I stop one of my outputs from coming out when I don't want it to?

Tags: java, output

so my code runs just as I want it to except for one flaw:
When the user inputs a number 1-10 it promptly ends and says thank you (as it should). When the user inputs a number that is not 1-10, it says thank you (the only error in my code) and then goes through the loop to a set max number of 3 times before telling the user to try again later. Please help me to stop it from saying thank you when the user gives an incorrect input on the first try! Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoopLab
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int MIN = 1;
        int MAX = 10;
        String userRating = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Rate Krabby Patties on a scale from " + MIN + " to " + MAX + ". ");
        int userRating2 = Integer.parseInt(userRating);
        if (userRating2 >= MIN || userRating2 <= MAX)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you!");
        }
        if (userRating2 < MIN || userRating2 > MAX)
        {
            for (int attempts = 1; attempts <= 2; attempts++)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input a number from " + MIN + " to " + MAX + ".");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again.");
                String userRating3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Rate Krabby Patties on a scale from " + MIN + " to " + MAX + ". "
                );
                int userRating4 = Integer.parseInt(userRating3);
                if (userRating4 >= MIN && userRating4 <= MAX)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you!");
                    break;
                }
                if (attempts == 2)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Come back later and try again.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged your code? if it's not within your valid block, this if statement: userRating2 >= MIN || userRating2 <= MAX will always return true. (also if it is a valid value). You'll want && instead of ||

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if (userRating2 >= MIN || userRating2 <= MAX)` you want `if (userRating2 >= MIN && userRating2 <= MAX)` in order to check for a range.
I.e. you want the logical AND of both borders being obeyed, not the OR.

Comment: I suspect that, if you do it right, you can replace one of the `if`s by an `else`.